Unable to Display File Content in RichTextBox
I'm encountering an issue where I'm trying to display the content of a file within a RichTextBox in my C# application, but the text doesn't appear in the RichTextBox even though it's successfully loaded into a string variable. Here's the relevant code snippet:
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
childForm1.richTextBox.Text = fileContent;

I've checked that fileContent contains the text I expect, but for some reason, it's not showing up in the RichTextBox. I've ensured that the RichTextBox is visible and has sufficient size, and that it's not set to read-only. Also, I've verified that the file path is correct and the file exists.
Could someone please help me identify what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it? Thank you!
I changed the method to your method but I have no change, also nothing is output, maybe I used your solution wrong? And I have one more question, how can I make the forms appear at a specific location, I tried setting the location but nothing changed.
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Lab10TP
{
   public partial class MainForm : Form
   {
       private ChildForm _editableChildForm = new ChildForm();
       ChildForm childForm1 = new ChildForm();
       ChildForm childForm2 = new ChildForm();
       public MainForm()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           this.IsMdiContainer = true;
           InitializeMenu();
           this.Load += new EventHandler(MainForm_Load);
       }
       

       private void InitializeMenu()
       {
           MainMenu _mainMenu = new MainMenu();
           MenuItem _fileMenu = new MenuItem("File");
           MenuItem _editMenu = new MenuItem("Edit");
           MenuItem _clearMenu = new MenuItem("Clear");

           _fileMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Open", OpenFile_Click));
           _fileMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Save", SaveFile_Click));
           _editMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Edit Picture", EditPicture_Click));
           _clearMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Clear Picture", ClearPicture_Click));

           _mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(_fileMenu);
           _mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(_editMenu);
           _mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(_clearMenu);

           this.Menu = _mainMenu;

       }

       private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
           openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
           if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
               if(ActiveMdiChild is ChildForm childForm)
               
                   try
                   {
                       string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
                       if (childForm.richTextBox.InvokeRequired)
                       {
                           childForm.richTextBox.Invoke(new
                           MethodInvoker(delegate
                           {
                               childForm.richTextBox.Text = fileContent;
                           }));
                           childForm.richTextBox.Refresh();
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           childForm.richTextBox.Text = fileContent;
                       }
                       childForm.SetStatus(openFileDialog.SafeFileName);
                       
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show($"Ошибка при открытии файла: {ex.Message}", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                   }
               
           }
       }

       private void SaveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (ActiveMdiChild is ChildForm childForm)
           {
               SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
               saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
               if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
               {
                   File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, childForm.richTextBox.Text);
                   childForm.SetStatus(saveFileDialog.FileName);
               }
           }
       }

       private void EditPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (ActiveMdiChild is ChildForm childForm)
           {
               childForm.SetEditable(true);
           }
       }

       private void ClearPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (ActiveMdiChild is ChildForm childForm)
           {
               childForm.ClearPicture();
           }
       }

       private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           int formWidth = (this.ClientSize.Width - 10) / 2;
           int formHeight = (this.ClientSize.Height - 10) / 2;
           int formHeightPicture = this.ClientSize.Height - 10;
           int form1LocationX = 0;
           int form1LocationY = 0;
           int form2LocationX = 0;
           int form2LocationY = formHeight + 10;

           
           childForm1.MdiParent = this;
           childForm1.Text = "Text Form 1";
           childForm1.Size = new Size(formWidth, formHeight);
           childForm1.Location = new Point(form1LocationX, form1LocationY);
           childForm1.Show();

           
           childForm2.MdiParent = this;
           childForm2.Text = "Text Form 2";
           childForm2.Size = new Size(formWidth, formHeight);
           childForm2.Location = new Point(form2LocationX, form2LocationY);
           childForm2.Show();

           
           _editableChildForm.MdiParent = this;
           _editableChildForm.Text = "Editable Picture Form";
           _editableChildForm.SetEditable(true);
           _editableChildForm.Size = new Size(formWidth, formHeightPicture);
           _editableChildForm.Location = new Point(formWidth, 0);
           _editableChildForm.Show();

       }
   }
}



You can also add
childForm1.richTextBox.Refresh()

after assigning value in Winforms ...
Try debugging line by line to see if the condition in line
if (childForm.richTextBox.InvokeRequired)

is true.
As for your second question:
You can use Location (as you probably did), but you also have to set the StartPosition to Manual.
This is the example :
namespace WinFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Location = new Point(600,200);


        }
    }
}

In the above code, 600 is the X coordinate, and 200 is the Y coordinate of the upper left corner of the form.
I tested this and it works!
I hope it helps!

It really works! Thank you very much! About the richTextBox, I just created an extra object.

Give this a bash 
if (childForm1.richTextBox.InvokeRequired)
{
childForm1.richTextBox.Invoke(new 
MethodInvoker(delegate 
{
    childForm1.richTextBox.Text = 
fileContent;
}));
}
else
{
childForm1.richTextBox.Text = fileContent;
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
